# artman googleapis google healthcare api and google's grpc fhir repo can't generate a client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I have artman so I can generate apis from the googleapis github repo which does not seem to have the healthcare api in it.  I then found the google fhir repo ( https://github.com/google/fhir ) with gRPC protobuf files in that but there seem to be ZERO artman*.yaml files nor any yaml files for that matter.

How can one generate java protobuf objects from the google fhir repo?  Or how does one generate clients for the google healthcare api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Healthcare has not released gRPC service definitions for the FHIR API. They might be released in the future but the FHIR standard is exclusively a REST API so the main focus is on the standards compliant interface.

(Discussed on FHIR zulip, but answering here so we have a record of it on stackoverflow as well)

Comment: thanks much!  upvote!  I love that you answered here as I dig through my own questions all the time!!! thanks!!

Comment: i was actually circling back to answer my own question...lol.  It's how I record my knowledge.